# Let $f_n$ bet monotonically increasing sequence of differentiable functions s.t $|f_n'(x)|\leq1$ and $f_n(0)=0$. Properties of the limit function.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n$ bet monotonically increasing sequence of differentiable functions s.t $|f_n'(x)|\leq1$ and $f_n(0)=0$. Properties of the limit function.

a) Show $f_n$ converges pointwise. We know by the bound on the derivative $|f_n(x)|\leq|x|$. Thus it is monotonic and bounded and so the pointwise limit exists.

b) Is the limit function $f$ continous? Yes $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\leq|x-y|$ then taking the limit $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq|x-y|$

c) Is $f$ differentiable? I think not necessarily. We know $f$ is Lipshitz and so it is differentiable a.e but I dont think we can prove f is differentiable everywhere.

I think $f_n=\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}-\frac{1}{n}$ is a counter example.

Is this correct?